# is it possible to tell which array element comparison resulted in true?

Tags: c++, arrays, comparison, parallel-processing

i have a three dimensional array which i am using as a bit table

```
   char bit_table_[X][Y][Z];
```

X is not larger than 20 but Y and Z will be very large.
the contents of every X's Y and Z will be compared parallely as follows (here real values of Y and Z will be computed using some hash functions).
My problem is; I don't know if there is any way at all to tell as to which of the X's give true in the condition checking of the if statment

```
if (((bit_table_[0][i][bit_index / bits_per_char]|
bit_table_[1][i][bit_index / bits_per_char])& bit_mask[bit]) != bit_mask[bit])
     return true;
```

or is there anyother way of doing it?

Comment: This is not at all clear.  For a start, what do you mean by "every X's Y and Z"?  X, Y and Z must be constants.

Comment: If you want to know which of the Xs "matched", why don't you simply test them individually rather than ORing them and losing that information in the process?

Comment: yes, Y,Z must be known at compile time so you must have a line like `int Y = 25` or a `"#define Y 25"`,... .

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:every"every X's Y and Z" is to mean, for all values of x(x=0 to x=max) all similar positions  y and z of the array

Comment: I have created and populated the array with no problem and even the parallel ANDing is done well. The problem is if it is possible to know which X dimension resulted in true

Comment: @John : in `char bit_table_[X][Y][Z];` X,Y and Z must have a known value at compile time....

Comment: @eharvest: yes you are right; X,Y and Z are defined constants

Comment: the some of the two x gives the true statement... not one o them. you are using `|` which is (binary OR) and not `||`...

Comment: bit_table_ contains only 0 or 1 value aka 1 binary value ?

Comment: so the unique case where the i statement is true is in my answer.  the unique solution is `bit_table_[0][i][bit_index / bits_per_char] = 0` and `bit_table_[1][i][bit_index / bits_per_char] = 0` and `bit_mask[bit] = 1`. so the answer of your question is both of the array elements at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test them individually to know which one resulted in true. Here is an example using a logical rather than bitwise OR to determine which one resulted in true.

```
bool x1 = false, x2 = false;

if(
   (x1 = (bit_table_[0][i][bit_index/bits_per_char] & bit_mask[bit]) != bit_mask[bit]) ||
   (x2 = (bit_table_[1][i][bit_index/bits_per_char] & bit_mask[bit]) != bit_mask[bit])
  )
{
    //Check x1 and x2 here
    return true;
}
```

Edit:

To expand on the previous example, and to satisfy the results of your original post you could also check if the combination of both is the reason it passes like so:

```
bool x1 = false, x2 = false, both = false;
size_t zindex = bit_index/bits_per_char;
if(
   (x1 = (bit_table_[0][i][zindex] & bit_mask[bit]) != bit_mask[bit]) ||
   (x2 = (bit_table_[1][i][zindex] & bit_mask[bit]) != bit_mask[bit]) ||
   (both = ((bit_table_[0][i][zindex] | bit_table_[1][i][zindex]) &
            bit_mask[bit]) != bit_mask[bit])
  )
{
    //Check x1 and x2 here
    //If both is true then neither x1 or x2 resulted in true alone

    return true;
}
```

Comment: but this has not the same result as his condition

Comment: he is doing a bit comparaison (`|` binary OR) not a || (OR)

Comment: But the way the question was asked it sound like he wants to know which of X (0 or 1) resulted in the expression returning true. If you are bitwise ORing them then it can not be determined. That is why I changed it to a logical OR. If that is not what the OP is looking for I will remove my answer.

Comment: maybe he does not understand well the condition he written. maybe he made a typing  mistake... no one of them x=0 o x=1 make the condition to be true, it is the association o them...

Comment: @joe: that is exactly what I wanted to do. I will still be open for more ways of doing it(if there are any)

Answer (score 0):

the solutionof your question is simple :  the if statement is true only if the array content for x=0 and x=1 have the same value  : 0. assumin that the array contain only binary values (0 or 1)
 `if ( (0 | 0 )& 1 ! = 1)` is true all other cases for bit_array or bit_mask make the statement false !!

---

if the array can contain other values than 0 or 1, you can neither say that the content of the array for x=0 or for x=1 that makes the statement true. it is the association of the both of them  :

simple example if you write  `if((0x0F | 0xF0) == 0)` when the condition is true, neither 0x0F or 0xF0 makes  it true !  it is the association of the two that make the condition true.

it is the same thing in your `if` statement.

Comment: the values coressponding to every x in the array are independent. they are agregated into one array just for the sake of this parallel ANDing. if you have seen joe's answer carefully he is ORing only the result of comparison of these independent elements. It still will not do what I was intending to do intitialy.

Comment: think a little of my remarks... I dont think you can make two conditions from your one condition with arithmetic operations